# How to draw these 2 functions on the same graph?

Tags: r

I want to draw 2 functions on the same graph, because the goal is to show whether one of them is uniformly higher than the other one.

Function 1 is:
f(x)

=0 if x <= -0.05,

=x+0.05 if -0.05<x<=0.95

=1 if x>0.95

Function 2 is: g(x)

=0 if x <= -0.16

=(2x+2-1.68)^2/2 if -0.16 <x<=0.34

=1-(1.68-2x)^2/2 if 0.34<x<=0.84

=1 if x>0.84

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just spell out the comparisons in detail, so you are sure to get them right:

```r
f <- function(x) {

    if( x <= -.05 )
        return(0)
    if( x <= .95 )
        return( x + 0.05 )

    ## the rest:
    return( 1 )

}

g <- function(x) {

    if( x <= -.16 )
        return(0)
    if( x <= .34 )
        return( (2*x+2-1.68)^2/2 )
    if( x <= 0.84 )
        return( 1-(1.68-2*x)^2/2 )

    ## the rest:
    return(1)

}

curve( Vectorize(f)(x), from=-1, to=2 )
curve( Vectorize(g)(x), from=-1, to=2, add=TRUE, col="red" )
legend( "right", col=c("black","red"), legend=c("f(x)", "g(x)"), lwd=2 )
```

[image: graphs of functions]

(The `Vectorize` bit of the code may look weird. It's there because the functions as written can only process one number at a time, while the `curve` function needs the function to process multiple values at once. Vectorize fixes that.)

### Improvements to function 1:

The first function can be simplified greatly, since it's simply clamping your x value to be in a fixed range

```
pmax(pmin(x+0.05,1),0) # would be one way
```

That expresion makes sure it never goes above 1, by taking the minimum of 1 and your variable value, and never goes below 0, by taking the maximum of 0 and your variable value.

If you have the `raster` package you can also use the clamp function from there:

```r
library(raster)
clamp( x+0.05, 0, 1 )
```

It just cuts any values out of the range to be the limits of the range.

You can add these to the graph yourself, one by one, to see that they end up right on top of the black line:

```r
curve( pmax(pmin(x+0.05,1),0) , add=TRUE, col="green" )
curve( clamp(x+.05,0,1)       , add=TRUE, col="blue" )
```

Answer (score 2):

You can have `plot` with `add=TRUE` like below

```
plot(f, -1.5, 1.5)
plot(g, add = TRUE)
```

where

```
f <- function(x) {
  ifelse(x <= -0.05,
    0, ifelse(x <= 0.95,
      x + 0.05, 1
    )
  )
}

g <- function(x) {
  ifelse(x <= -0.16,
    0,
    ifelse(x <= 0.34,
      (2 * x + 2 - 1.68)^2 / 2,
      ifelse(x <= 0.84,
        1 - (1.68 - 2 * x)^2 / 2,
        1
      )
    )
  )
}
```

such that

[image]